# Strong Parameters Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

Any idea why this isn't working?

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit({:book_ids => []}, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title, :company, :phone, :business_email, :business_phone)
end
```

Unpermitted parameters: `book_ids`

Comment: How does the params hash look like? Can u share the server log.

Comment: @user3317140 I have resolved the issue. OP is yet to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :title, :company, :phone, :business_email, :business_phone, :book_ids => [])
end
```

You must be passing `book_ids` as an `array` in your params, in that case you should permit them as `:book_ids => []` **and also at the end.**

As per the chat session, OP had an issue with the drop down as it was set as `multiple: false` instead of `multiple: true`. Also, in order to facilitate the `update` action, a `selected` option needs to be specified.

Comment: Thats strange. Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror